# Regex for xml schema that accept latin characters

Tags: xml, regex, utf-8

I need a regex for xml schema that describes "names that start with an uppercase letter, and that they are composed of at least two separate words."

I come up with this `([A-Z])([a-z]*)\s(([A-Z])([a-z]*)(\s)*)+` and it works. Examples:

```
John Russel  

John Russel Peter

Super Mario
```

I think it could be shorter but I don't know how to do it.

But my problem is to accept latin characters like `é`, `à` and `ã`.  What can I do to accept those characters?

I have to accept names like:

```
Super Mário 
José Super Mário
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{L}` to match any letter from any kind of language.

```
^[A-Z]\p{L}*(?:\s[A-Z]\p{L}*)+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/26)

Comment: Thanks! It does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^[A-Z]\S+\s\S+
```

example : http://regex101.com/r/eF0uB4/1

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly for two words. What the best way two accept more that two words?

Answer (score 1):

Try this also.

```
([A-Z]+\S+)*(\s)*
```